# Atom opens a new file called ATOM_DISABLE_SHELLING_OUT_FOR_ENVIRONMENT=false

Tags: atom-editor

Whenever I start Atom it opens two files, one called:

```
ATOM_DISABLE_SHELLING_OUT_FOR_ENVIRONMENT=false
```

And the other one:

```
/usr/bin/atom
```

It's really annoying and I don't understand how to fix it. From what I understand it is some sort of environment configuration bug, but I can't find what's causing it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I am going to make several assumptions. You are running on Ubuntu and you've installed Atom via Snap.

If these assumptions are correct the cause of the issue is a misconfigured application menu item from the Snap package author.

**To fix it you just need to run this command:**

```sh
sudo sed -i 's/Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=\/var\/lib\/snapd\/desktop\/applications\/atom_atom.desktop \/snap\/bin\/atom ATOM_DISABLE_SHELLING_OUT_FOR_ENVIRONMENT=false \/usr\/bin\/atom %F/Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=\/var\/lib\/snapd\/desktop\/applications\/atom_atom.desktop ATOM_DISABLE_SHELLING_OUT_FOR_ENVIRONMENT=false \/snap\/bin\/atom %F/' /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/atom_atom.desktop
```

---

**TL;DR {**

Here is a detailed explanation of what's causing the issue and what the command above does. It may be useful if the file has been changed since the answer was written.

The actual cause for the bug is that this menu item file:

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/atom_atom.desktop
```

It has a typo in it and what should be environment variables are set after calling
the `atom` executable, resulting in Atom treating it as arguments in the form of
files that it should open.

```sh
#                                                                                     ▼ Executable   ▼ Not an environment variable                   ▼ Not an executable
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/atom_atom.desktop /snap/bin/atom ATOM_DISABLE_SHELLING_OUT_FOR_ENVIRONMENT=false /usr/bin/atom %F
```

It should instead be:

```sh
#        ▼ Environment variable                                                       ▼ Environment variable                          ▼ Executable
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/atom_atom.desktop ATOM_DISABLE_SHELLING_OUT_FOR_ENVIRONMENT=false /snap/bin/atom %F
```

The solution above uses `sed` to search and replace the file and fix the issue.

**}**

***NOTE:*** The command will work until the Snap author updates the menu item file (`.desktop`) when hopefully the issue would have been resolved.

Comment: Great answer, not only the way to fix the problem, but a neat explanation too.  Answer like this one are what makes stack overflow so awesome.

Comment: I installed ATOM via snap, then I removend and installed it via console. Every two weeks or so I still get this back, have to exectue the command and then it works again.

Comment: This answer was so helpful. I've been facing the same challenge but have resolved it now. But when I launched atom the first time after running the above command, the error still appeared. All I did is to close atom and relaunch it and everything works fine. Thanks so much @Itay Grudev

Comment: @john that's probably because you closed Atom with those files opened and you have the "Restore Previous Windows On Start" option active

Comment: This only partially worked for me. I can start atom from the terminal and the extra "files" are gone, but atom won't start from the desktop icon. I get a spinning wheel for a few moments, but no atom window appears and no atom process is left running. I suspect it is objecting to the fact that I edited the file with a text editor rather than using the 'sed' command given. So maybe the file has a new inode now? My next move is to uninstall, reinstall, then use the sed command with the in-place option.

Comment: Okay, I had two issues. First, I made my own typo when I edited the file. My bad. Second, I didn't appreciate that snapd needed to be restarted for the change to take effect... at least that's how it appeared to behave. Anyway, it's all good now. Thanks!